# Replace command not working

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I want to replace this code

```
 for($counter=0;$counter<10;$counter++)
 {
     $yyarr[$counter]=$counter+2004;
 }
```

with

```
 for($counter=2004;$counter<=date("Y");$counter++)
 {
     $yyarr[$counter-2004]=$counter;
 }
```

I am using

```
sed -e 's/for\(\$counter=0;\$counter<10;\$counter++\)\n\t+{\n\t+\$yyarr\[\$counter\]=\$counter+2004;\n\t+}/for\(\$counter=2004;\$counter<=date\("Y"\);\$counter++\)\n{\$yyarr\[\$counter-2004\]=\$counter;\n}/g'
```

But can't get it through. Trailing whitespace needs to be ignored.

Comment: I do not think that sed will handle multi-line regexes. There may be some versions that do, but not in my experience. I would recommend something like `perl -p -i -e` instead of `sed` for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` processes lines of data.  As such, the way you're attempting to search/replace your pattern wouldn't work.  You could make use of [hold space](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) to search your pattern, though.

The following might work for you:

```
sed -n '1h; 1!H; ${g; s/\s*for(\$counter=0;\$counter<10;\$counter++)\s*\n\s*{\s*\n\s*\$yyarr\[\$counter\]=\$counter+2004;\s*\n}/\nfor($counter=2004;$counter<=date("Y");$counter++)\n{\n\t$yyarr[$counter-2004]=$counter;\n}/ p}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/for($counter=0;$counter<10;$counter++)\n{\n    $yyarr\[$counter\]=$counter+2004;\n}/for($counter=2004;$counter<=date("Y");$counter++)\n{\n    $yyarr\[$counter-2004\]=$counter;\n}/g' file
```

You are facing problem with new line replacement `\n`. The above code will fix it.